# Where is the error? (Basic Actionscript 2.0)

Tags: variables, integer, actionscript-2, addition

So I am making an extremely basic application on AS2.0 but for some reason, I can't do it.
It consists of two textboxes, (variables named "num1" and "num2") an equal sign converted into a button (variable named "btn") and a final textbox (variable named "res") to show the result of adding two numbers, which are the ones given in "num1" and "num2" textboxes. Here's what I've tried:

```
on(click) {
Number(num1) + Number(num2) = res;
}
```

I've also tried

```
on(click) {
Number(num1) + Number(num2) = res.text;
}
```

but none of this seem to work. One of these throw a "NaN" at the "res" textbox and the other one simply throws out nothing.
Where's the problem?

Comment: BY THE WAY: The addition is supposed to be made when the equal button is clicked or pressed :D

Answer (score 0):

```
on(click) {
    _root.res.text = Number(_root.num1.text) + Number(_root.num2.text);
}
```